# Creating non-overlapping segments in Global Descriptor Table

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, protected-mode

In this bootloader, I'm trying to set up separate global descriptor table entries for kernel code and user code (albeit with some simplifications, see the comments). Creating disjoint segments is causing a triple fault, even though the segments have the same privilege levels (ring 0).

The following code functions as expected. It defines a single code segment and a single data segment, thus offering no protection. The 1024 bytes of the source file are written to a virtual floppy, so "floppy" here is synonymous with "this file".

```
;***BEGIN SECTOR 1 OF FLOPPY***
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00              ; standard bootloader location

main:   
    CLI             
    XOR AX, AX          ; zero the segments (relative to ORG)
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV AX, 0x9000          ; stack begins at 0x9000-0xFFFF
    MOV SS, AX
    MOV SP, 0xFFFF
    STI             

; Load the second sector of this floppy into memory at 0x07C0:0x0200 (deliberately lacks error checking)
    MOV AH, 0x02       ; BIOS INT 0x13 "read sector" function
    MOV AL, 1          ; Number of sectors to read
    MOV CH, 0          ; Cylinder/track
    MOV CL, 2          ; Sector of floppy to read
    MOV DH, 0          ; Head
    MOV DL, 0          ; Disk number (here, the floppy disk) (unnecessary since DL defaults to boot disk)
    MOV BX, 0x07C0     ; Segment containing the destination buffer (i.e. the current segment)
    MOV ES, BX
    MOV BX, 0x0200     ; Destination buffer offset
    INT 0x13

    CALL installGdt        ; Create the global descriptor table and load its pointer into GDTR

    CLI
    MOV EAX, CR0
    OR EAX, 1
    MOV CR0, EAX
    JMP 0x08:protected_mode



; Offset 0 in GDT: Descriptor code=0x00
gdt_data: 
    DD 0                ; null descriptor
    DD 0 

; Offset 8 bytes from start of GDT: descriptor code 0x08
; kernel code:              
    DW 0xFFFF           ; bits 0-15 (segment limit)
    DW 0x0000           ; bits 16-31 (low 2 bytes of base address)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 (middle byte of base address)
    DB 10011010B        ; bits 40-47 ("segment in memory" bit, privilege bits, descriptor bit, descriptor type, virtual memory access bit)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 (granularity, segment type, bits 16-19 of segment limit)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 (high byte of base address)

; Offset 16 bytes from start of GDT: descriptor code 0x10
; kernel data:              
    DW 0xFFFF           ; bits 0-15 (segment limit)
    DW 0x0000           ; bits 16-31 (low 2 bytes of base address)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 (middle byte of base address)
    DB 10010010B        ; bits 40-47 ("segment in memory" bit, privilege bits, descriptor bit, descriptor type, virtual memory access bit)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 (granularity, segment type, bits 16-19 of segment limit)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 (high byte of base address)

end_of_gdt:
gdt_description: 
    DW end_of_gdt - gdt_data - 1    ; size of GDT minus 1 (for GDTR)
    DD gdt_data             ; base of GDT




installGdt:
    CLI         
    PUSHA
    LGDT [gdt_description]      
    STI
    POPA
    RET

times 510-($-$$) DB 0       ; pad rest of sector
DW 0xAA55           ; add bootloader signature
;***END SECTOR 1 OF FLOPPY***



;***BEGIN SECTOR 2 OF FLOPPY***
BITS 32
protected_mode:
    MOV     AX, 0x10        ; set data segments to kernel data
    MOV     DS, AX
    MOV     SS, AX
    MOV     ES, AX
    MOV     ESP, 0x90000        ; stack begins from 0x90000

    MOV EAX, 5              ; a test to use in qemu register dump, to see if code reached this point
    JMP $



times 1024-($-$$) DB 0      ; pad rest of sector
;***END SECTOR 2 OF FLOPPY***
```

On the other hand, when changed to the following, a triple fault results. Note that I expect the second sector to be loaded into memory at 0x07C0:0x0200, so I set the limit of the kernel segments to 0x01FF, while the user segments start at 0x0200.

```
;***BEGIN SECTOR 1 OF FLOPPY***
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00              ; standard bootloader location

main:   
    CLI             
    XOR AX, AX          ; zero the segments (relative to ORG)
    MOV DS, AX
        MOV ES, AX
        MOV AX, 0x9000          ; stack begins at 0x9000-0xFFFF
    MOV SS, AX
    MOV SP, 0xFFFF
    STI             

; Load the second sector of this floppy into memory at 0x07C0:0x0200 (deliberately lacks error checking)
    MOV AH, 0x02       ; BIOS INT 0x13 "read sector" function
    MOV AL, 1          ; Number of sectors to read
    MOV CH, 0          ; Cylinder/track
    MOV CL, 2          ; Sector of floppy to read
    MOV DH, 0          ; Head
    MOV DL, 0          ; Disk number (here, the floppy disk) (unnecessary since DL defaults to boot disk)
    MOV BX, 0x07C0     ; Segment containing the destination buffer (i.e. the current segment)
    MOV ES, BX
    MOV BX, 0x0200     ; Destination buffer offset
    INT 0x13

    CALL installGdt        ; Create the global descriptor table in RAM

    CLI
    MOV EAX, CR0
    OR EAX, 1
    MOV CR0, EAX
    JMP 0x18:protected_mode



; Offset 0 in GDT: Descriptor code=0x00
gdt_data: 
    DD 0                ; null descriptor
    DD 0 

; Offset 8 bytes from start of GDT: descriptor code 0x08
; kernel code:              
    DW 0x01FF           ; bits 0-15 (segment limit)
    DW 0x0000           ; bits 16-31 (low 2 bytes of base address)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 (middle byte of base address)
    DB 10011010B        ; bits 40-47 ("segment in memory" bit, privilege bits, descriptor bit, descriptor type, virtual memory access bit)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 (granularity, segment type, bits 16-19 of segment limit)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 (high byte of base address)

; Offset 16 bytes from start of GDT: descriptor code 0x10
; kernel data:              
    DW 0x01FF           ; bits 0-15 (segment limit)
    DW 0x0000           ; bits 16-31 (low 2 bytes of base address)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 (middle byte of base address)
    DB 10010010B        ; bits 40-47 ("segment in memory" bit, privilege bits, descriptor bit, descriptor type, virtual memory access bit)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 (granularity, segment type, bits 16-19 of segment limit)
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 (high byte of base address)

; Descriptor code 0x18
; user code:                ; (see immediately above for descriptions of bit fields)
    DW 0xFFFF           ; bits 0-15 
    DW 0x0200           ; bits 16-31 
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 
    DB 10011010B        ; bits 40-47 (privilege set to ring 0 for simplicity)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 

; Descriptor code 0x20
; user data:                ; (see immediately above for descriptions of bit fields)
    DW 0xFFFF           ; bits 0-15 
    DW 0x0200           ; bits 16-31 
    DB 0x00             ; bits 32-39 
    DB 10010010B        ; bits 40-47 (privilege set to ring 0 for simplicity)
    DB 01000000B        ; bits 48-55 
    DB 0x00             ; bits 56-63 

end_of_gdt:
gdt_description: 
    DW end_of_gdt - gdt_data - 1    ; size of GDT minus 1 (for GDTR)
    DD gdt_data             ; base of GDT




installGdt:
    CLI         
    PUSHA
    LGDT [gdt_description]      
    STI
    POPA
    RET

times 510-($-$$) DB 0       ; pad rest of sector
DW 0xAA55           ; add bootloader signature
;***END SECTOR 1 OF FLOPPY***



;***BEGIN SECTOR 2 OF FLOPPY***
BITS 32
protected_mode:
    MOV     AX, 0x20        ; set data segments to user data
    MOV     DS, AX
    MOV     SS, AX
    MOV     ES, AX
    MOV     ESP, 0x90000        ; stack begins from 0x90000

    MOV EAX, 5              ; a test to use in qemu register dump, to see if code reached this point
    JMP $



times 1024-($-$$) DB 0      ; pad rest of sector
;***END SECTOR 2 OF FLOPPY***
```

Comment: I haven't read the code thoughtfully, but the base for the "segment" 0x18 should be 7e00h

Comment: The offset of `protected_mode`, as far as NASM is concerned, is 0x7e00, so your far jump instruction jumps to 0x18:0x7e00. Looking up selector 0x18 in the GDT gives a base of 0x200, which when added to the offset gives a linear address of 0x00008000. The code you want to execute is actually loaded at linear address 0x00007e00.

Comment: What @MargaretBloom says is true, but that GDT you have sets the base at 0x200 in memory. `JMP 0x18:protected_mode` would then be the same as `JMP 0x18:0x7e00` . Problem is that the base of selector 0x18 is 0x200 alread so you are actually jumping to 0x7e00+0x200 in physical memory. A quick hack to see if that is the case is to do `JMP 0x18:(protected_mode-0x200)` . This will create a new problem because your protected mode code will be using an ORG of 7e00 but you need code relative to 0x7c00.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Doesn't nasm add the ORG 7C00h to 0200h to get 7E00h?

Comment: Only for the label `protected_mode`. It doesn't modify the contents of your GDT table.

Comment: @Vale132 NASM can't know how you are going to use your data.

Comment: _NASM_ has no idea that you reconfigured memory in the target machine (via LGDT) and are using a selector that has a base of 0x200 rather than typical 0x0

Comment: Oh ok, thanks everyone. I'll look into those issues.

Comment: Another fix would be to keep your original `jmp 0x18:protected_mode` and use _NASM_ section feature that lets you set a new origin point. Right before your 32-bit protected mode code you could add the line `section pm, vstart=0x7c00`

Comment: A better question might be, what were you originally trying to achieve. The question makes me think we are dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271768) . I'm wondering if you might have wanted to set the base of the 0x18 selector to 0x7e00 and your protected mode code to run based on an origin point of 0x0000. Very hard to tell. Once in protected mode the processor doesn't use real mode segment:offset addressing anymore.

Comment: Note that LGDT instruction doesn't modify registers and is atomic with respect to interrupts so there's no need to use PUSHA/POPA or CLI/STI around it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It seems that using JMP 0x18:0x0000 and setting the base of segment 0x18 to 0x7E00 fixes the problem, but I guess I would have to use something like your solution whenever I want to work with labels? I guess using hard coded addresses will become infeasible.

Comment: You're right, I'm having trouble defining the problem clearly since I'm just barely learning how to get into protected mode. I'm trying to create a "user space" from which code will then be able to use call gates for "system calls". I will probably want to use labels at that point rather than hard-coded addresses, so I need to study your solution.